# Find order of reaction with respect to A and B and find the rate law expression for 2A+B -> C

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

[image]

Please help me in this chemistry question

Comment: Try to look at two entries where either concentration of A or B is constant, and observe how the the rate and the concentrarion of the other reactant varies

Comment: Can you please give more information, this is little to begin with

Comment: For example, in experiment 1 and 2, conc of A is constant. Also, you can see that as concentration of B changes, rate of reaction remains unaffected by that change. So this means that the rate would be independent of concn of B. Now similarly,try for A

Answer (score 1):

1- Write the rate law expression :
 $r=k[A]^x[B]^y$

2-Take experiment one and two :
 $$5.07\times{10^{-5}}=k[0.2]^x[0.3]^y\tag{1}$$
 $$5.07\times{10^{-5}}=k[0.2]^x[0.1]^y\tag{2}$$
3- Divide equation one by equation two:
$$\frac{5.07\times{10^{-5}}}{5.07\times{10^{-5}}}=\frac{k[0.2]^x[0.3]^y}{k[0.2]^x[0.1]^y}\tag{3a}$$
$$1=3^{y}\tag{3b}$$
$$3^{0}=3^{y}\tag{3c}$$ ,so:y=0(the order of reaction with respect to B), now : the rate law expression :
 $r=k[A]^x[B]^{0}=k[A]^x$

4-Take experiment two and three:
 $$5.07\times{10^{-5}}=k[0.2]^x\tag{4}$$
 $$1.43\times{10^{-4}}=k[0.4]^x\tag{5}$$
5-Divide equation five by equation four:
$$\frac{1.43\times{10^{-4}}}{5.07\times{10^{-5}}}=\frac{k[0.4]^x}{k[0.2]^x}\tag{6a}$$
$$2.8=2^{x}\tag{6b}$$
$$log2.8= x log 2\tag{6c}$$,so:$x\approx{1.5}$(the order of reaction with respect to A), now : the rate law expression :
 $r=k[A]^{1.5}[B]^{0}=k[A]^{1.5}$